# Getting rid of FFmpeg non-existng PPS error

Tags: c++, c, video, ffmpeg, decode

I am using ffmpeg to decode videos. I am aware that the error I am getting is due to the frame/sliceHeader is decoded and the Picture Parameter Set information is not there. I am just curious if anyone knows a way to get rid of this error? My video is successfully decoding but in the debugger this error makes the metadata hard to read.

**The error is :**

```
non existing PPS 0 referenced
decode_slice_header error
no frame!
```

******** My code is in C ******

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, my solution turned out to be :
Hope it helps anyone using ffmpeg in c!

```
av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_QUIET);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the FFmpeg [logging](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/log_8c.html) facilities - you can use [av_log_set_callback](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__log.html#ga14034761faf581a8b9ed6ef19b313708)  to provide your own logging callback and either just ignore everything, or filter by log level, it is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case of use, i was able to still receive critical errors, but no longer decoder errors with following parameters:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel panic
```

Here is a snippet of documentation of available loglevels:

```
-loglevel [repeat+]loglevel | -v [repeat+]loglevel
  Set the logging level used by the library. Adding "repeat+" indicates that repeated log output should not be compressed to the first line and the "Last message repeated n times" line will be omitted. "repeat" can also be used alone. If "repeat" is used alone, and with no prior loglevel set, the default loglevel will be used. If multiple loglevel parameters are given, using ’repeat’ will not change the loglevel. loglevel is a string or a number containing one of the following values:

  ‘quiet, -8’
  Show nothing at all; be silent.

  ‘panic, 0’
  Only show fatal errors which could lead the process to crash, such as and assert failure. This is not currently used for anything.

  ‘fatal, 8’
  Only show fatal errors. These are errors after which the process absolutely cannot continue after.

  ‘error, 16’
  Show all errors, including ones which can be recovered from.

  ‘warning, 24’
  Show all warnings and errors. Any message related to possibly incorrect or unexpected events will be shown.

  ‘info, 32’
  Show informative messages during processing. This is in addition to warnings and errors. This is the default value.

  ‘verbose, 40’
  Same as info, except more verbose.

  ‘debug, 48’
  Show everything, including debugging information.

  ‘trace, 56’
```

Comment: This worked if I run my code from the cmd, thank you very much! Sadly I am using C and I am using the local debugger though so it doesn't seem to work in that situation. Any suggestions?